# Single query to copy data from 3 tables into a single empty table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, performance, query-performance

In an interview today, I was asked if I could write a single query to copy data from 3 source tables to an empty destination table.

I started saying "I will use a temp table or table variables", however the interviewer said "no, I want to see a single statement or query."

I was blank :(

Can someone share the right answer?

Comment: Maybe with "select into"? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: Perhaps: `INSERT INTO EmptyTable (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...) ;`

Comment: Just curious, what kind of position was the interview about?

Answer (score 3):

> Step 1: First prepare the data set through sql query as per the
>   requirement.
>
> Step 2: Insert the prepared record set into a new table.

**Note:**  In `'Union All'` number of columns in select list for all the table must be same.

**Note :** In `JOIN` you can prepare the data from different table through through joins as per business requirement and insert into a new table.

**For Ex:**

```
select * into newtable from
( 
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
union all
select * from table3
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with data modifying common table expressions.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

It will run as a single query with multiple inserts to the same table from different sources.

```
with 
ins1 as (
    insert into dest(id, name)
    select id, name
    from source1
)
,ins2 as (
    insert into dest(id, name)
    select id, name
    from source2
)
,ins3 as (
    insert into dest(id, name)
    select id, name
    from source3
)
select l;
```